# Sort by Date not working for Date type field

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I am trying to do a simple sort by date on my search results. but it doesn't seem to work. Please help me in identifying what am I missing.

Mapping -

```
{"document" : {
    "properties" : {
      "content" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "modifiedDate" : {
        "type" : "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Date is indexed in following format-

```
"modifiedDate": [
                  "2014-02-03T13:17:55.000Z"
               ]
```

The search query is pretty big, so pasting only the sort part of the query below -

```
"sort": [
     {
       "modifiedDate": {
         "order": "desc" , "missing" : "_last" , "ignore_unmapped" : true
       }
     }
   ]
```

tried , just order parm too -

```
"sort": {"modifiedDate": {"order": "desc"}}
```

but the results are not sorted.

In the search results result I see following text under sort, I was expecting miliseconds -

```
"sort": [
               "P\u0002\u0000\u0000"
        ]
```

Please advise what am I missing, thank you so much for your help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something going on that is not obvious based on the information you have given. Full curl recreations (https://www.elasticsearch.org/help/) will really help pin point the issue. Here is what I got when I walked through your scenario with the 1.3.0 release:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/testindex" -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "modifiedDate": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'


curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/testindex/document/1" -d'
{
  "modifiedDate": [
                  "2014-02-03T13:17:55.000Z"
               ]
}'

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/testindex/document/2" -d'
{
  "modifiedDate": [
                  "2014-02-04T13:17:55.000Z"
               ]
}'
```

Then run the search:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/testindex/_search" -d'
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "modifiedDate": {
        "order": "desc",
        "missing" : "_last", 
        "ignore_unmapped" : true
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

And here is the response:

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "testindex",
            "_type": "document",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "modifiedDate": [
                  "2014-02-04T13:17:55.000Z"
               ]
            },
            "sort": [
               1391519875000
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "testindex",
            "_type": "document",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "modifiedDate": [
                  "2014-02-03T13:17:55.000Z"
               ]
            },
            "sort": [
               1391433475000
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```